# Foreground service and app standby

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

According to Android Marshmallow documentation, an app with a foreground service it's not set in a standby state from system. However it isn't clear to me if it's an exit condition. I mean: does an app already in standby state that executes a foreground service exit from this state?